Wrong format in environment variables reading PRIVATE KEY - vercel after deployment nestjs app + firebase
I deployed my NestJs appliaction to vercel. and added my environment variables through the UI.
when running firebase admin add and trying to send a message I get an error Notification sending
failed FirebaseAppError: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp()
Locally everything works fine.
I am setting my private key like this:
"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCO6yCT21bLs2lt\nE+UIrqzJZA8Dsc5D9pTVsk7cp8THgdhg6Bf16Np6gNkp3FjOxlzCyusKugTakM33lFJxk67UJw1BQapy3Z\nU4iC1puvMKjwwOf4oSBHqPZ9\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
I am consoling the private key in my app when I get the error. its looks formatted
here is my code.
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
  private defaultApp: admin.app.App;

  constructor() {
    const databaseURL = process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL;
    const projectId = process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID;
    const clientEmail = process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL;
    const privateKey = process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n").trim();

    if (!projectId || !clientEmail || !privateKey) {
      throw new Error('Firebase environment variables are not set correctly.');
    }

    this.defaultApp = admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId,
        clientEmail,
        privateKey,
      }),
      databaseURL,
    });
  }

  async sendNotification(title: string, body: string,deviceToken: string,): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const message: Message = {
        notification: {
          title,
          body,
        },
        token: deviceToken,
      };

      const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
      console.log('Notification sent successfully', response);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Notification sending failed', e);
      throw new Error('Notification sending failed');
    }
  }
}

tried to format the key myself remove all the quotes. Nothing works.
Locally everything works fine.
I tried:
process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n").trim(); -- not working
process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n") -- not working.
const privateKey = Buffer.from(process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY, 'base64').toString('utf8').replace(/\\n/g, "\n");

